How to create a standardized header in z/OS ISPF panel definition
This has always bugged me. My system has about 150 panels and all of them have the same header. What I want to do is insert a few lines of code from a standardized header member at the top of all these panels. This is too much duplicated code for my liking.
I thought )IM would do it but either it doesn't or i'm doing it wrong.
The main panel is this...
)ATTR
  + TYPE(TEXT) COLOR(WHITE)
  _ TYPE(INPUT) COLOR(RED)
  % TYPE(OUTPUT) COLOR(BLUE)
)BODY
)IM STDHEAD
+
+ ENTER SUB-SYSTEM CODE _SUBSYSCD+
+
)INIT
)PROC
)END

The member STDHEAD would contain something like this...
+
+You are in system %SYSCD+
+

Forgot to mention that I had the STDHEAD member in the same library as the calling member and in a library in the concatenation for the LIBDEF ISPPLIB.

)IM is used in skeletons, not in panels.  To reuse code in panels, you can write them in DTL and put the common code in either an embedded entity or a macro:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/3.1.0?topic=reference-dtl-macros
Then you'd convert the DTL source to panel source.  The panel source would still contain the repeated code in each panel, but now you only have to update it in one place.

That's what I thought but )IM is listed as a control statement in the Dialog Developer's Guide. That's what made me think it was workable.
